# Is there any way to start Firefox with --marionette and hide the pink/gray stripes over the address bar?

Tags: firefox, marionette, firefox-marionette

I know that I can start Firefox in remote controllable state as follows:

1. Close all instances of Firefox
2. Start Firefox with the poorly documented --marionette command line switch:

   "c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" --marionette

Firefox will start, and apart from the little robot icon, and the quite annoying pink/gray stripes over the address bar, it will operate normally.

Is there any way to hide those pink/gray stripes?